# Solving depressed cubic: extra solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

In an attempt to solve $x^3+px=-q$

Note,

$$(a-b)^3+3ab(a-b)=a^3-b^3$$

Let $p=3ab$ and $-q=a^3-b^3$.  Then we have,

$$(a-b)^3+p(a-b)=-q$$

$a-b$ is a solution to the cubic equation $x^3+px=-q$.  If we assume $p \neq 0$ then we have $b=\frac{p}{3a}$, otherwise solving the depressed cubic is simple. It is important to note that if $p \neq 0$ then neither $a$ nor $b$ can be zero.

We substitute $b=\frac{p}{3a}$ in to $-q=a^3-b^3$ and eventually get,

$$a^3=\frac{-q \pm \sqrt{q^2+\frac{4}{27}p^3}}{2}$$

That gives $6$ possible choices for $a$ (at most) and $6$ possible choices for $b$. I would like to finish, and find $a-b$.

---

My Question:

May someone please explain why this way of Cardano's method gives only $3$ different solutions instead of what appears to be $6$.

Comment: The correct formula should work for special cases for $p$ and $q$, e.g. $p = 0$. You can then argue that if you have to subtract the cube roots with a choice of signs and inserting phase factors to make a certain spacial case work, then that's true in general.

Comment: As you say, you **have** the answer: $a=p/(3b)$, but are dismissing it for some reason that is not apparent to me.

Comment: The reason is that simplifying $1/root(.....)$ is a hard job, which I would rather avoid for that reason @LordSharktheUnknown