# Find the factor of the given equation.

Tags: cubics

Find the factor of  the equation 
$x^2-42.5 x^{\frac{2}{3}}-78.4=0$ ?
I have tried it by substituting $x^{\frac {2}{3}}$ by $z$ and get a cubic equation $z^3-42.5z-78.4=0$ and tried to solve it by using Cardan's method but it was too lengthy. Please help me to solve it in any simplest way. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The roots are messy. Accept it.

Comment: There's no way out no matter how hard you wish. also, check with [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E3%E2%88%92425%2F10*z%E2%88%92784%2F10%3D0)

Comment: Cardano's method is relatively simple

Comment: Check this out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318064/solving-depressed-cubic-extra-solutions

Comment: But for this case cardan's method takes very huge calculation.  How can I solve it for only 2 marks.

Answer (score 2):

To make things cleaner, consider the equation to be $$ z^3-\frac{425}{10}z -\frac{784}{10}=z^3-\frac{85 }{2}z-\frac{392}{5}=0$$ From the discriminant, you know that there are three real roots. So, use the [trigonometric method](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/The_solution_of_cubic_equations) for solving the roots and get $$Q=-\frac{85}{6}\qquad R=\frac{196}{5} \qquad \theta=\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1176 \sqrt{\frac{6}{85}}}{425}\right)$$ and then the three roots given by $$z_k=\sqrt{\frac{170}{3}} \cos \left(\frac {2k \pi}3+\frac{1}{3} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1176
   \sqrt{\frac{6}{85}}}{425}\right)\right)$$ using $k=0,1,2$.

Comment: Thank you sir @Claude Leibovici

Comment: @Iamdark. You are welcome ! I hope I did not make any mistake with these numbers; but the idea is this.